# How can I implement bivariate normal Gaussian noise?

Tags: python, random, gaussian, noise

I want to implement complex standard Gaussian noise in python or C. This figure shows what I want to implement.

[image]

And first I implement it in python, like this.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl

size = 100000
BIN = 70

x = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,size)
y = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,size)

xhist = pl.hist(x,bins = BIN,range=(-3.5,3.5),normed = True)
yhist = pl.hist(y,bins = BIN,range=(-3.5,3.5),normed = True)
xmesh = np.arange(-3.5,3.5,0.1)
ymesh = np.arange(-3.5,3.5,0.1)
Z = np.zeros((BIN,BIN))
    for i in range(BIN):
     for j in range(BIN):
         Z[i][j] = xhist[0][i] + yhist[0][j]
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xmesh,ymesh)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

However, it is not standard complex Gaussian noise.

The output figure become:

[image]

I think Gaussian noises are additive, however, why it become so different?

I already tried to change the parts of code

```
x = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,size)
y = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,size)
```

to

```
r = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,size)
theta = np.random.uniform(0.0,2*np.pi,size)
x = r * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(theta)
```

however, the result was same.

Please tell me the correct implementation or equation of bivariate standard Gaussian noise.

Answer (score 0):

So sorry.It's my mistake.

Joint probability is defined by the product, not summation. I was a perfect fool!

So

```
Z[i][j] = xhist[0][i] + yhist[0][j]
```

term must become

```
Z[i][j] = xhist[0][i] * yhist[0][j]
```

And I checked

```
for i in range(BIN):
    for j in range(BIN):
        integral = integral + Z[i][j] * 0.01
```

will be 1.0.

So if we need complex standard Gaussian noise, we should do adding the real standard Gaussian noise to real part and imaginary part.

This is the graph for comparing.

[image]

[image]